# Power Automation issue

Tags: automation

Here, I attached the screenshot That I have been currently facing the issue of running macros using Power Automation Desktop. I have tried different solutions. But, so far I haven't solved the error, and shows like the attached image. I changed the security settings in the Excel. But, It didn't work.
can anyone suggest any other solution apart from changing the security settings from Excel

https://i.stack.imgur.com/snMcE.png

Make sure that no Excel file is currently being edited or blocked by a pop-up dialog, or that the target sheet is not protected. Also, make sure that:
• The macro-containing file isn't included in the disabled items list.
• The macro is available in this workbook and macros are not disabled.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Instead of linking to an image, please type out your code in your post.

Comment: It is a low-code platform technology. There is no code. It is a drag-and-drop content only.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close your Excel from task manager or use process terminator before starting this flow
2. Make sure that VBA is not blocked by Excel it self. you can check it from Excel setting  (Option)
3. Make sure you are able to see your Macros in excel if you created in excel